# How to append options to dynamically created select elements with jquery in Laravel blade file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, dom

Good day. I have a form in which I can dynamically add groups on input elements. I have select elements among them.
In my controller, I returned the data to populate the select element to the blade file.
After this, I then append the data to the select element using Jquery.
The problem is that, this works for the initial form group (elements), but it does not work for the dynamically generated one.
What could be the cause please? Or is there a better way of doing this?
This are my blade (html) and jquery codes

Blade file

```
                         <button id="add_counsel_button" type="button">Add</button>
                                <h5>Step 3: Case Counsels</h5>
                                <div id="dynamic_wrapper">
                                    <div class="field_wrapper" id="row1">
                                        <input type="text" style="width:50%!important;display: inline!important;"
                                            name="counsels[]" id="name1" data-number=1 class="form-control counsel-name">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="counsel_id[]" id="id1">
                                        <div class="counsel-list" id="counsel-list1"></div>
                                        <select name="roles[]" style="width:21%!important;display: inline!important;"
                                            class="form-control roles-list">
                                            <option value="#">Select Role</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <select name="representations[]"
                                            style="width:21%!important;display: inline!important;"
                                            class="form-control reps-list">
                                            <option value="#">Select Representation</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            //Setting the value from the controller
            var roles = {!! json_encode($roles->toArray()) !!};
            var reps = {!! json_encode($representations->toArray()) !!};

            $.each(roles, function(i, item) {
                $('.roles-list').append($('<option>', {
                    value: item.id,
                    text: item.role
                }));
            }); //want this to be appended to all 'roles-list' classes

            $.each(reps, function(i, item) {
                 $('.reps-list').append($ '<option>', {
                        value: item.id,
                        text: item.type
                    }); 
            });

            
            $(document).on('click', '#add_counsel_button', function() {
                i++;
                $('#dynamic_wrapper').append('<div class="field_wrapper" id="row' + i +
                    '"><input type="text" id="name' + i + '" data-number="' + i +
                    '" style="width:50%!important;display: inline!important;" name="counsels[]" class="form-control counsel-name"><input type="hidden" name="counsel_id[]" id="id' +
                    i + '"><div class="counsel-list" id="counsel-list' +
                    i +
                    '"></div> <select name="roles[]" style="width:21%!important;display: inline!important;" class="form-control roles-list"> <option value="#">Select Role</option></select><select name="representations[]" style="width:21%!important;display: inline!important;"class="form-control reps-list"><option value="#">Select Representation</option></select><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" id="' +
                    i +
                    '" style="display: inline!important;"title="Remove field"> <span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a></div>'
                );
            });
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console?

Comment: No, I am not getting any error in the console

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the options before appending the select tag. Change the code like below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        //Setting the value from the controller
        var roles = {!! json_encode($roles->toArray()) !!};
        var reps = {!! json_encode($representations->toArray()) !!};
        roles_str = '';
        reps_str = '';
        $.each(roles, function(i, item) {
            roles_str += '<option value="'+item.id+'">'+item.role+'</option>';
        }); //want this to be appended to all 'roles-list' classes

        $.each(reps, function(i, item) {
            reps_str += '<option value="'+item.id+'">'+item.type+'</option>'; 
        });

        
        $(document).on('click', '#add_counsel_button', function() {
            i++;
            $('#dynamic_wrapper').append('<div class="field_wrapper" id="row' + i +
                '"><input type="text" id="name' + i + '" data-number="' + i +
                '" style="width:50%!important;display: inline!important;" name="counsels[]" class="form-control counsel-name"><input type="hidden" name="counsel_id[]" id="id' +
                i + '"><div class="counsel-list" id="counsel-list' +
                i +
                '"></div> <select name="roles[]" style="width:21%!important;display: inline!important;" class="form-control roles-list"> <option value="#">Select Role</option>'+roles_str+'</select><select name="representations[]" style="width:21%!important;display: inline!important;"class="form-control reps-list"><option value="#">Select Representation</option>'+reps_str+'</select><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" id="' +
                i +
                '" style="display: inline!important;"title="Remove field"> <span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a></div>'
            );
        });
 });
```